# Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have following the tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

I have a button showing up and it looks like it works but when I login with a work account I get

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and
> cannot access the application '' in that tenant. The account needs to
> be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a
> different account.

It seems to work with a gmail account but not another tenant's account.

My question is how do I get it to work with another tenants account

Here are my 3 custom xml files
https://easyupload.io/m/w0gxlj

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, please try the below:**

I created an Azure AD Application and configured redirect URI:

[image]

Now, I created a **Policy Key** like below:

[image]

To configure Azure AD as Identity Provider, I added the **ClaimsProvider** in the **`TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`** file like below:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
<Domain>testaadb2c01</Domain>
<DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
<DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
<Description>Login with your Contoso account</Description>
<Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
<Metadata>
<Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/testaadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
<!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
<Item Key="client_id">CLIENTID</Item>
<Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
<Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
<Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
<Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
<Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
</Metadata>
<CryptographicKeys>
<Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADAppSecret"/>
</CryptographicKeys>
<OutputClaims>
------
</OutputClaims>
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
------
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
<DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
<Metadata>
<Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">OBJECTID</Item>
<Item Key="ClientId">CLIENTID</Item>
</Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
<Metadata>
<Item Key="client_id">CLIENTID</Item>
<Item Key="IdTokenAudience">AUDIENCE</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="XXXXXX"/>
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="XXXXXX"/>
</InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
</ClaimsProviders>
```

[image]

**When I run the custom Policy, I got the login screen successfully like below:**

[image]

When I tried to login with **`AzureAD User account`**, I am able to  sign-in successfully like below:

[image]

[image]